# What type of brake line flare is this?

Tags: brakes, fitting, flare, line

I need to replace some brake line (on my 2001 Seville STS) leading to the flex hose (at the rear right wheel). I have removed the fitting from the hose, but I don't recognize the flare.  See photo below.

I assumed all brake lines require a double lap flare - but what type of flare is this? Is this a DIN/bubble flare?

I have a tool for making double lap flares, can I use that?  I could start making a double lap flare (press the button till flush) and then stop before it folds in on itself...just not sure if that's safe or the right way to make this.  Assuming's its a DIN/bubble flare.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what the line side looks like?

Comment: I cut the end of the line right where it goes into the fitting (so I could use a socket to remove the fitting).  So it's a squished mess.  What are you looking for there?

Comment: I wish I would have read closer, sorry. If this leads to the flex hose, this doesn't get a flared end you'll put on here. You need to replace the flex hose. Inside the flex hose fitting, the angle of what's there will match this and seal. There's a name for it, but I don't remember off the top of my head. It isn't something you make, though. It's in the fitting.

Comment: Yikes - I don't think I can find a replacement hose for a 23 yr old car (actually that would have the SAME flare)...I would have to get a custom hose with a SAE or DIN flare...In that case I may have no choice but to try making the same shape with my double flare tool

Comment: Your flare tool WILL NOT WORK. I'm still not sure which hose you're talking about, but you should have no problems finding a replacement hose. Before you "think" you can't find something, look. A 23 year old car is nothing. Look on RockAuto.com or go to Autozone. My money is on you'll find what you're looking for.